# Word displays mail merge data from Excel with the wrong number of digits

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, mail-merge

I'm using mail merge in Word, with the data coming from Excel.

The formula for the data in Excel is number/6 and I limit it to display just one decimal number, e.g. `91.7`.

But in Word, it displays as `91.6666666666`.

I would like it to show `91.7` in Word as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you mail merge, the actual stored value is used, not the *displayed* value. You need to set the stored value to the number of digits required.

For example if the source value is in `A1` you need to use this formula for the mail merge data:

```dart
=ROUND(A1/6,1)
```

Comment: Will try soon mr robinCTS. Thank you sooo much!

Comment: Hi robinCTS..still not good..some of my data still display like 97.0000000003..more 0 this time..

Comment: @cliffe I don't know how that's possible. It should have worked. However, try `=TEXT(A1/6,"0.0")` instead.